# SpEL not able to extract attribute value from Scala object

Tags: spring, scala, spring-el

I have a simple Scala class called `Case`

```
case class Case(
             @(Id@field) var id: String,
             var state: CaseState = new OpenCaseState,
             var notes: List[CaseNote] = new ArrayList(),
             var assignedGroups:Set[String] = new HashSet(),
             var aclTemplateIds: Set[String] = new HashSet()
           ) extends Serializable { }
```

I created an instance of this class called `a_case`, setting `id` as `123`. I am trying to get the value of the `id` attribute. I tried this

```
var parser: ExpressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser
var context: EvaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(a_case)
var extractedId = parser.parseExpression("'id'").getValue(context).asInstanceOf[String]
```

All I get is `"id"` in my `extractedId` variable. When I try to parse `"id"` without the single quotes, I get an exception saying the property `id` is not found in `Case`. Am I missing something here or is this a Scala issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpEL can do that for you if your `id` has getter.

I'm not well with Scala, but:

> BeanProperty
>
> You can annotate vals and vars with the `@BeanProperty` annotation. This generates getters/setters that look like POJO getter/setter definitions. If you want the `isFoo` variant, use the `BooleanBeanProperty` annotation. The ugly `foo$_eq` becomes

```
setFoo("newfoo");
getFoo();
```

https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/java.html